# error: type ‘class Eigen::Tensor<double, 3>’ argument given to ‘delete’, expected pointer

Tags: c++, eigen, tensor

I am trying to delete a tensor created with Eigen::Tensor

N1, N2 , N3 are vectors of int

```
N1 << 1,2,3
N2 << 4,3,5
N3 << 9,7,8


 for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
{
 Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> Hs(N1(i),N2(i),N3(i));

 Hs.setZero();

 delete Hs;
  }
```

How can I delete my tensor? I have to clear it and change its size

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why are you trying to `delete H;`? That object was allocated on the stack, and it's destructor will be called when it falls out of scope.

Comment: *I am trying to delete a tensor* -- Elaborate on why you are trying to delete a tensor.  Yes, the issue is that the variable is on the stack, and that `delete` applies to only pointers, but what were you really trying to accomplish?  Is it to save memory?  Is it to "clear" the tensor?

Comment: I need to clear the tensor and modify its size. It is inside a for loop, at each step the tensor should be "clear" and with a different size.

Comment: There is no loop in the code you show. And as an aside, learning C++ on the go while programming by guesswork is not an effective technique. Not for C++ anyway.

Comment: Also, your mention of a loop now makes this classic [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You want to do `X`, you decide `Y` is the way, but when it unsurprisingly fails you ask about `Y` instead of `X`.

Comment: I vote to close. Maybe open a new question.

Comment: Don't post code in comments please. Rather [edit] your question into a coherent representation of your actual problem.

Comment: @SaraFiore *I am sorry I though it would have been enough* -- The very nature of the issue requires you show the code in proper context.  A loop body with a type declared within the body has *huge* implications pertaining to your problem.  But we see no loop.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I edited. Thank you for your time

Comment: @SaraFiore -- Well, on each iteration, that is a brand new `Hs` variable being created.  So there is no need to `delete` at all.  At the bottom of the loop, the current `Hs` is destroyed and a new one is created again at the top of the loop.  This is basic C++ stuff you should know (scoping rules and variable lifetimes).

Comment: Besides what has been said already, you should also read how (and why) to provide a [mcve]. People are often more happy to help, if they can just copy+paste the code from a question.

Answer (score 2):

Your compiler is telling you what is wrong. `H` is not a pointer and was not allocated on heap. Simply remove `delete H` and you are fine as it will be destructed when it goes out of scope.

So this is how you would create a 3x3 matrix:

```
#include <Eigen/Sparse>


int main(void)
{
    Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3> H;
    H.setZero();
}
```

Just for completeness (do not do that if you do not have to): if you had written

```
Eigen::Tensor<double, 3> H* = new Eigen::Tensor<double, 3>(N1,N2,N3);
```

then delete would be appropriate.